# Is it possible to fire action through voice command ios 7

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios7

I want to develop a video recording application. When ''start'' button is pressed camera will be opened to record video after that- voice command  will be used that is ''START'' on this voice command recording will start.

Comment: Well great for you. What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you could [speechKit](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/Help/DragonMobileSDKReference_iOS/Introduction.html) and in your app you would have to make speechKit listen as app start's or video interface is present. Now whatever user would say it will record and send it to it's server and give you back the text of what server fetch from user's voice. Then put a check if any STOP word come's and stop your recording of video ,and vice-versa for START keyword. Here's a [link-raywenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/60870/building-ios-app-like-siri) just for how to use speechKit. Now go ahead and give it a try and let me know if you need anything else.